# Method overriding concept in Thread C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++17

In my code, there are two methods work() and work(var), I want to pass that function under thread, whenever i pass one of that method i got an error "No matching constructor for initialization std::thread"

My Code :

```
void work(){ // something do} 
void work(int var){// something do}
int main(){

   std::thread myThread_1(work,34); // this line of code give me error
   
  myThread_1.join();
  return 0;
}
```

How can i solve this problem guys ? please help me

Comment: Please make a [mre]. Show the exact code that gives the error.

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass overloaded functions as parameters. You need to either:

Explicitly cast to the desired overload:

```
std::thread myThread_1(static_cast<void (*)(int)>(work), 34);
```

or Use a lambda:

```
std::thread myThread_1([](int var) { work(var); }, 34);
// or better yet:
std::thread myThread_1([] { work(34); });
```